# Accessibility of supplementary content

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to add "invisible" supplementary content to HTML elements and I would like to avoid creating new elements in the DOM. I would also like to maintain accessibility as much as I can (i.e. read out by screen readers VoiceOver and JAWS). How would I do this?

Note: In my context, supplementary content mostly consists of help text, but there are some instances where additional information will appear. For sighted users, this content might appear in a non-modal alert box or tooltip, for instance.

1. I can use the `title` attribute, but there seems to be [quite a few problems](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/) associated with this. Also I'd like to be able to customize the appearance of the text (whether it be a custom tooltip or widget) and `title` will produce the browser's default tooltip.
2. I can put the content into the [`aria-label` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label), but this seems to be more appropriate for *alternative* content rather than *supplementary* content.
3. The most accessible method seems to be [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute), however that would require the content to be put into a separate DOM element with an ID along with ARIA role `tooltip`, which isn't really feasible at this point in time.
4. Finally there's the [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), which are there for content to be used in scripts and such, but there's nothing about the accessibility of that.

An attribute is preferable because I can also access the contents using the CSS `attr()` method if I do not use JavaScript. Then again, do screen readers read generated content?

Comment: Just curious - what is your specific objection to creating new elements in the DOM?

Comment: I concur with Tim, and what elements are you thinking about adding this to

Comment: I think you need to give an example of what you are trying to do. If its help text, what are you helping with: for an abbreviation use `<abbr>`. Context dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid creating DOM elements, there are three options:

- [CSS hiding + clipboard](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/protecting-email-with-css/)
- [Generated content](http://alistapart.com/article/aria-and-progressive-enhancement#snippet3)
- [Aria Live Regions](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_ARIA_Live_Regions_or_role%3Dalert_to_Identify_Errors)

If not, use a dummy image for supplementary content:

```
<label for="username">User Name
  <img role="presentation" src="required.png" alt="Required" />
</label>
<input type="text" id="username" aria-required="true" />
```

**References**

- [Accessibility support for CSS generated content](http://tink.uk/accessibility-support-for-css-generated-content/)